# Unable to retrieve jSON data when query has spaces in PHP

Tags: php, json

### What I'm trying to do

I'm trying to use the **RottenTomatoes API** to retrieve information about a movie.

If I search for *Frozen*, I use this script:

```
$q = 'Frozen';

$json_link = 'http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.json?q='.$q.'&page_limit=10&page=1&apikey=%myAPIkey%';
$json_info = file_get_contents($json_link);

$data = json_decode($json_info,true);

$results = $data['movies'];

foreach($results as $result){
    echo $result['title'].'<br/>';
}
```

and it returns the list of movies:

```
Frozen
Frozen
Frozen River
The Frozen Ground
Frozen Land (Paha maa)
Frozen Assets
Frozen Days (Yamim Kfuim)
Frozen City (Valkoinen Kaupunki)
Frozen Stupid
```

This works for all single-word queries.

### What isn't working

Unfortunately, when searching for a term with multiple words, such as *Harry Potter*, I cannot retrieve any data at all.

I have tried `$q='Harry Potter'` and `$q='Harry%20Potter'` but neither returns any value.

When using `var_dump` on `$json_info`, it simply reads:

```
bool(false)
```

However, if I visit the URL (http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.json?q=harry%20potter&page_limit=10&page=1&apikey=%myAPIkey%), I see a full list of all 20 movies associated with the search term:

[image: Search result for multi-word query]

How can I retrieve this information in PHP when the URL is clearly correct?

Comment: Try `$q=urlencode("Harry Potter")`

Comment: Did you applied [urlencode](http://www.php.net/urlencode) on the **q** or by hand?

Comment: Yes, urlencode($query) works perfectly, if you could reply with that as an answer I'll tick it! I haven't come across that function before, why is it necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [urlencode](https://www.php.net/urlencode)

```
$q=urlencode("Harry Potter")
```